# Template-based dictionary creation out of a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
TEMPLATE = ['sing.','pl.','mode']
DATA = [
['alpha','alphas',0],
['beta','betas',2],
['omega','omegas',3]
```

I want to create a list of dictionaries that would be like:

```
[ {'sing.': 'alpha', 'pl.': 'alphas', 'mode':0},
{'sing.': 'beta', 'pl.': 'betas', 'mode':2},
{'sing.': 'omega', 'pl.': 'omegas', 'mode':3} ]
```

Is there a quick way to do it in Python 3?

Comment: This isn't a place where  people do works for you.. Show your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` to weave the template together with a single data entry. The resulting sequence can be passed to the `dict` constructor. Use a list comprehension to create the entire sequence:

```
>>> [dict(zip(TEMPLATE,d)) for d in DATA]
[{'pl.': 'alphas', 'sing.': 'alpha', 'mode': 0}, {'pl.': 'betas', 'sing.': 'beta', 'mode': 2}, {'pl.': 'omegas', 'sing.': 'omega', 'mode': 3}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` function, `dict` constructor and list comprehension, like this

```
print([dict(zip(TEMPLATE, items)) for items in DATA])
```